# Magento Call custom block inside another custom block

Tags: magento

I am new to magento, so please forgive me if I have asked anything wrong. I have created a custom module for instagram Login, I just want to call a particular block from that instagram module to another layout file. I have called that block printed in my view page using

```
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media_new'); ?>
```

My block got called but functionalities are working and form is not submitting.

My custom module layout file. Instagram.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
      <reference name="content">
      </reference>
</default>
     <instagram_index_instagram_signup>  
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>magenthemes/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
             <block type="core/template" name="instagram.signup" template="instagramlogin/Instagram_signup.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </instagram_index_instagram_signup>  
</layout>
```

I want to call the above block to another module layout file:
My another module layout page:

```
             <marketplace_vendor_login>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>magenthemes/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
    </reference>
     <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
     <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="facebookfree/init" name="belvg_facebookfree_block">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="facebookfree/settings/enabled" ifvalue="1">
                <template>belvg/facebookfree/block.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
    <block type="marketplace/vendor_login" name="customer_form_login" template="nbmpmarketplace/login.phtml" >
        <block type="facebookfree/links_button" name="belvg_facebookfree_button" template="belvg/facebookfree/form/button.phtml" />
          <block type="core/template" name="instagram.signup" as="media_new" template="instagramlogin/Instagram_signup.phtml"></block>
    </block>
    </reference>
</marketplace_vendor_login>
```

Here I have called my custom block, then printed in my view page as:

```
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media_new'); ?>
```

My controller code for instagram:

```
class Blazedream_Instagram_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
        {
public function instagram_signupAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){  
        if($this->getRequest()->getPost('instagram-email')){
            $instagram_email  = $this->getRequest()->getPost('instagram-email');
            $customer_model = Mage::getModel('instagram/instagram');
            $site_customer = $customer_model->checkCustomer($instagram_email);
            if($site_customer){
                $instagram_customer = Mage::getModel('instagram/instagram')->getCollection()
                                                  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $site_customer));
                if(count($instagram_customer)==1){
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setInstagramEmail($instagram_email);
                    $this->_redirect('instagram/index');    
                }else{
                    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Email Id Already Registered.');
                    $this->_redirect('sellerlogin');    
                }
            }else{
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setInstagramEmail($instagram_email);
                $this->_redirect('instagram/index');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('instagram.signup');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
 }
```

It is not coming into this controller function, That i have used for instagram module.

My view page: instagramlogin.phtml

```
      <div style="display: none">
    <style type="text/css">
        #cboxContent.newsletterbox {
        <?php if($backgroundImage){?> background-image: url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'/wysiwyg/magenthemes/newsletter/'.$backgroundImage;?>);
        <?php }?> background-position: left top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: <?php echo $backgroundColor;?>;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="mt_instagram" class="block block-subscribe">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-newletters col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="block-title">
                    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Join our Mail List Through Instagram!') ?></span></strong>
                </div>
                <div class="row-none">
                    <div class="popup_message">
                        <div class="intro">
                            <?php echo $desc; ?>
                        </div>
                        <form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'instagram/index/instagram_signup'; ?>" method="post" id="instagram-validate-detail">
                            <div class="block-content">
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input name="instagram-email" type="text" id="mt-newsletter" placeholder="Enter your email id"
                                           value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-email"/>


                                    <div class="actions">
                                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>"
                                                class="button">
                                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am getting my custom form also..But the controller is not getting called and functionalists are not working, only I am getting the form.

Can anyone help Me?

Comment: " But the controller is getting called and functionalists are not working" - which controller are you talking about? And what functions are not working? You only showed the code that is responsible to add the block to the layout (which works) and not for whatever is *not* working

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.. I am getting only the form but the form is not posting.

Comment: <instagram_index_instagram_signup> block is getting called.

Comment: I still don't see relevant code. Please show `instagramlogin/Instagram_signup.phtml`

Comment: ok. I will post my controller code.

Comment: Can you please post your modules config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is my first ever answer on stackoverflow, I will try my best to explain.

To start with, let me brief you about the block calls in Magento; any particular type of Block(.php files in Block folder) has a corresponding content/template (.phtml in template folder) file to render the data fetched from Model (.php in Model folder).

In your layout (.xml for your module in layout folder), you have added a block that is of type (core/template) so it will call the file Mage_Core_Block_Template.php and can access all its methods. However, if you want to create a custom block you can update layout (instagram module) file like this.

```
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
    </default>
         <instagram_index_instagram_signup>  
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>magenthemes/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>
            </reference>
            <reference name="content">
                 <block type="instagram/instagram" name="instagram.signup" template="instagramlogin/Instagram_signup.phtml"></block>
            </reference>
        </instagram_index_instagram_signup>  
    </layout>
```

And create a file in Block folder with name Blazedream_Instagram_Block_Instagram.php and then you will be able to call custom methods to the block template. 
Ex.-

```
    class Blazedream_Instagram_Block_Instagram extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
      public function customMethod()
      {
        $response = array('a', 'b', 'c');

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
      }
    }
```

Update you controller action call to

```
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
```

Now, to add this block inside another custom module, update its layout like

```
    <fname_controller_action>
         //path controller path on which you want to add/update the block
        <update handle="my_custom_handle" />
    </fname_controller_action>

    <my_custom_handle>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="where_you_want_to_add">
                <block type="instagram/instagram" name="my.custom.block" as="instagram.signup" template="template_path/instagram.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </my_custom_handle>
```

or add a constructor inside the block file Blazedream_Instagram_Block_Instagram.php like -

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('template/instagram.phtml');
    }
```

and call the block in any template file with the below code

```
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('instagram/instagram')->toHtml();

You might need to update your layout file in this case.
```

If you do everything correctly, you should be able to call $this->customMethod() in the template file instagram.phtml

Thanks! Pardon me if I could not explained it properly.